# Accessing a GameObject in Unity with Different Copies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, gameobject

I'm creating a Quest System in my RPG (Role-Plating Game) and it can be get through an NPC (Non-Player Character). I've attach a script on my main character that can check whether or not you've get a quest from an NPC. Here's the code:

```
public class QuestTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public QuestGiver questGiver;
    public Button AcceptQuest;
    public OpenQuestWindow questWindow;

    public void acceptQuest()
    {
        questGiver.questAccepted = true;
    }
}
```

Now I've attach a script on my NPC for them to give a quest to the player. Here's the code for the NPC:

```
 public class QuestGiver : MonoBehaviour
 {
    public bool questAccepted = false;
 }
```

When the player clicks on the NPC, a window will appear which will show the player what will be his/her quest objective. For now, I've created 2 NPC's and attach them both the QuestGiver script. Here's some screenshot:

[image]
[image]

On the accept button, I've used the acceptQuest() function on my QuestTracker which is attached to the player, but I can't set a specific value for QuestGiver because I have multiple copies of NPC not just one.

[image]

What I want is to set the QuestGiver on the player via runtime. I know it can be implemented by using OnMouseOver() function or Raycast. I know the logic, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using static variable can solve your problem. Set player questGiver as static.

```
public class QuestTracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static QuestGiver questGiver;
    public Button AcceptQuest;
    public OpenQuestWindow questWindow;

    public void acceptQuest()
    {
        questGiver.questAccepted = true;
    }
}
```

And then when an Npc make a quest, change players questGiver via Npc's script.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    QuestTracker.questGiver = this;
}
```

Edit: By the way, you will not see questGiver variable in inspector when you change it as static. Test it with Debug.Log().

Comment: Really nice solution O.o I love how you used OnMouseDown() advantage. +1

Comment: I already have different dialogue for the NPC and it turns out to be what I wanted.

Comment: You can see questGiver in inspector by having another public variable called questGiverInspector of type QuestGiver of course, and then just write in void Update questGiverInspector = questGiver;

Answer (score 0):

You should make an array of all the QuestGivers in the game and assign their values on the Start() function on any script. Add an global variable to the QuestGiver class to identify which QuestGiver is who, integer is fine for example. Put this code into the acceptQuest()

```
QuestGiver giver = null;
switch (questGiver.ID)
{
    case 0:
    giver = classThatHasTheArray.QuestGiverArray[0];
    break;
}

giver.questAccepted = true;
```

Regards, TuukkaX.